# How can I access a selenium chromedriver instance across multiple functions?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

The only way I'm able to persist a chromedriver instance across multiple functions is if I open the driver first, and then run the rest of the functions.

For example, here I set up the driver:

```
def start_driver():

 service = Service('C:\\Users\\Jonbi\\Desktop\\coding_projects\\coding_utilities\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe') # v115 chromedriver.exe path
 options = Options()
 options.binary_location= 'C:\\Users\\Jonbi\\Desktop\\coding_projects\\coding_utilities\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe' # v115 new ChromeFortesting browser path
 options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=options)
 url = 'https://tracer.sos.colorado.gov/CampaignFinance/Reports/ReportParameters.aspx?Form=RPT-CF-CAND-001&Public=A1Z2Y7B3-7901-567W-C1PU-8V5EU9ERSI10'


 driver.get(url)
 return driver
```

I have several other functions that perform various operations, they look similar to this:

```
def define_search_parameters(year):

 print('Searching for new candidates...')
 year_index = indices_dict['years'].get(str(year)) 
 select_election_year = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID,'ctl00_Content_lstElectionYear'))
 select_election_year.select_by_index(year_index)
 time.sleep(4) 
 generate_report_button = driver.find_element(By.ID,"ctl00_Content_btnGenerateReport")
 generate_report_button.click()
 time.sleep(4)
 return driver
```

If I attempt to group the functions together in a main function, like this, I get a "No Such Window Exception". It seems like the other functions can't access the driver.

```
def update_main(year):

 driver = start_driver()
 define_search_parameters(year)
 download_csv_report()
```

However, If I remove the `start_driver` function from the `update_main` function and instead run the `start_driver` function first, and followed by `update_main`, the functions all work just fine and have no issue accessing the driver instance. Adding the 'detach' option to the driver didn't seem to help. While everything technically works if I just manually run `start_driver` first, it prevents me from group everything into a single neat main function that I can run from terminal. Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions